# Can't run python script at boot

Tags: fedora

In Fedora, I have `/etc/rc.local` that looks like this...

```
# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi


/usr/bin/screen -dmS wixel python "/home/myuser/python-usb-wixel-xdrip/python-usb-wixel.py"
exit 0
```

Yet after I boot, `sudo screen -r wixel` presents me with `There is no screen to be resumed matching wixel.`

Running `/usr/bin/screen -dmS wixel python "/home/myuser/python-usb-wixel-xdrip/python-usb-wixel.py"` starts my script, and `sudo screen -r wixel` follows its output.

Why won't my script start at boot?

I tried `sudo chmod a+rx /etc/rc.local`

Comment: Try to use the full path of `python`, e.g. `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Not too sure why that would work specifically when omitting the full path in the CLI works :/

Comment: Boot PATH might not be the same (and is usually not) as the one defined in your login shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not specified in your description, but I spot the Fedora label here. Fedora has used `systemd` for a while so, if you use it, you need to enable rc.local service.

Check systemd service within `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service` for more info.

Your script should go to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` (`ExecStart` line; instead of `/etc/rc.local`). The file should be provided by `initscripts` package, but I didn't found it on my system. Don't be afraid than and create it. But don't forget to set correct permissions and a shebang (eg. `#!/bin/bash`). Than you have to start and enable `rc-local.service`.

This should work for you:

```
# as root
mv /etc/rc.local /etc/rc.d/rc.local
sed -i '1i #!/bin/bash' /etc/rc.d/rc.local
chmod 0755 /etc/rc.d/rc.local
# this run the script immediately (!)
systemctl start rc-local.service
# this enables service to run it within boot
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

`systemd` runs the script with the `start` parameter. It didn't break anything, but you can use it within your script.

This is quite good for your question about `rc.local`. Anyway better solution should be to add a new systemd service. I'm too lazy to write it there, because there is a few manuals on internet :) Eg.: http://www.linuxveda.com/2014/04/28/autostart-process-gnu-screen-systemd/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Regarding your instruction; the last line doesn't work for me. Should it be `systemctl enable rc-local.service`? It appears to have started after a reboot when I changed that line!

Comment: Yeah, sure, that was a typo. `systemctl ...` is the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have my service running correctly :)